# How to create or get a domain name as mentioned in step 2 in AKS

Tags: kubernetes-ingress, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/tree/main/docs/examples/grpc

In the above link under **Prerequisites - 2nd point**, it is mentioned to have a domain name configured to Ingress controller.

How to create or get a domain name in AKS?
I have a grpc application, trying to implement the same steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two Options, for both you need an own a domain Name (you can buy it at namecheap.com or godaddy.com).

First option: Switch the [domain DNS resolution to Azure.](https://edi.wang/post/2017/6/2/migrate-domain-dns-to-azure#:%7E:text=Go%20to%20the%20management%20portal,old%20DNS%20records%20to%20Azure.).

Second option: Create the AKS and add it as CNAME (AKS public FQDN, i would prefer this over using the IP) to the DNS records of your domain.